# Elasticsearch NEST update by script

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to update some fields by script. In Postman I'm sending the following request:

```
https://search.test.com/items_example/item/en_01_2/_update
```

the request's body:

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.Title = params.Title; ctx._source.Desc = params.Desc",
    "params": {
        "Title": "New Title",
        "Desc": "New Desc"
    }  
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how I can send this request using NEST. Can someone please help me?
Elasticsearch 5.4.1 version, NEST 5.6.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update it with your index settings & query

```
var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
var scriptParams = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Title", "New Title"},
    {"Desc", "New Desc"}
};

var response = elasticClient
    .UpdateByQuery<dynamic>(q => q.Query(rq => rq.Term(....))
    .Script(script =>
        script.Inline(
            $"ctx._source.Title = params.Title;" +
            $"ctx._source.Desc  = params.Desc ;"
        )
    .Params(scriptParams));
```

Edit: If you're looking for just Update, just change the syntax to

```
var response = elasticClient.Update<dynamic>(
    "items_example/item/en_01_2" //This is your document path
    , request => request.Script(
        script =>
            script.Inline(
                    $"ctx._source.Title = params.Title;" +
                    $"ctx._source.Desc  = params.Desc ;"
                )
                .Params(scriptParams)));
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is looking for `.Update(...)` rather than `.UpdateByQuery(...)`. Could you provide an example of the former?

Comment: @Lowkey, `elasticClient.Update<dynamic>` works fine! Great thanks

Answer (score 3):

If someone is here looking for the solution with NEST 6x version, please see below

```
public async Task UpdateId(MetaData request)
{
   try
   {                
      var scriptParams = new Dictionary<string, object>
      {
         { "Id",request.Id}
      };
      var script = $"ctx._source.Id= params.Id;";                   
      var indexResponse = 
         await EsClient.UpdateByQueryAsync<Doc>(
            qd => qd.Index(request.IndexName)                          
                    .Conflicts(Conflicts.Proceed)
                    .Query(
                       rq => rq.Term("_id", request._id))
                               .Script(
                                  s => s.Source(script) 
                                        .Params(scriptParams)
                               )
                    )
         );
      if (!indexResponse.IsValid)
      {
                        
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
}

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "_doc")]
public class Doc
{
    
}
```

Comment: tnx a lot for sharing ! exactly what I needed, and could not find this easily on the documentation

Comment: 2 years on and there's still no decent examples of using scripts in the NEST documentation! thanks for this